# Why does GSL give error about mismatched dimension when there isn't one

Tags: c++, gsl

I'm wrapping GSL's ODE functions is a class I'm defining. When written with no class involved, the functions are working perfectly. However, when using the class I get an error after the second `gsl_odeiv2_evolve_apply_fixed_step`, getting the error `gsl: evolve.c:317: ERROR: step dimension must match evolution size`. I'm confused why the first step should work but the second shouldn't. In printing out the dimension of the `step` and `evolve` functions I get the same thing. Here's what I have for my class and what I'm calling inside the `main()` function.

```
class DynSys {
public:
  DynSys(const size_t size, double startTime, double endTime, double stepSize,
         double* iState,
         int (*func)(double, const double*, double*, void*),
         int (*jac)(double, const double*, double*, double*, void*),
         const gsl_odeiv2_step_type* T = gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd)
    : T(T), size(size), t(startTime), t1(endTime), h(stepSize) {
    y = new double[size];
    y = iState;
    yPrev = new double[size];
    s = gsl_odeiv2_step_alloc(T, size);
    c = gsl_odeiv2_control_y_new(1e-6, 0.0);
    e = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_alloc(size);
    sys = { func, jac, size, 0 };
  }

  ~DynSys() {
    delete [] y;
    delete [] yPrev;
    gsl_odeiv2_evolve_free(e);
    gsl_odeiv2_control_free(c);
    gsl_odeiv2_step_free(s);
  }

  void step() {
    printf("e dim: %ld\n", e->dimension);
    printf("s dim: %ld\n", s->dimension);
    printf("y: %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f\n", y[0], y[1],
           y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5]);
    tPrev = t;
    yPrev = std::copy(y, y+size, yPrev);

    int status = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_apply_fixed_step(e, c, s, &sys,
                                                    &t, h, y);
    if (status != GSL_SUCCESS) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", gsl_strerror(status));
      throw std::logic_error(gsl_strerror(status));
    }
  }

  double getT() {
    return t;
  }

  void setY(double* y) {
    y = y;
  }

private:
  const gsl_odeiv2_step_type* T;
  gsl_odeiv2_step* s;
  gsl_odeiv2_control* c;
  gsl_odeiv2_evolve* e;
  gsl_odeiv2_system sys;

  const size_t size;
  double t;
  double t1;
  double h;
  double* y;

  double tPrev;
  double* yPrev;
};
```

and then

```
int main() {
  double state[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.796975, 0.11637, 0.0185312};
  const size_t size = 6;
  DynSys system(size, 0.0, 40.0, 1e-3, state, func, jac);

  system.step();
  printf("t: %.5f\n", system.getT());
  system.step();
  printf("t: %.5f\n", system.getT());

  return 0;
}
```

edit: Here's a link to the GSL functions [GSL ODE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/ode-initval.html)

Comment: perhaps you can link the online manual for those gsl functions

Comment: Good idea, I've added the link now.